# Why doesn't Java allow package in Generic method definition?

Tags: generics, java

**Problem:**

Java seems to have build issues when attempting to define a Generic method as follows:

```
public <otherPackage.TypeA, otherPackage.TypeB> 
    void someMethod (otherPackage.TypeA a, otherPackage.TypeB b)
```

Due to name project requirements, I have several classes that have the same name. In particular, in my implementation, I have a class in namespace `myPackage`called `Thing`, that has a method with arguments `otherPackageOne.Thing` and `otherPackageTwo.Thing`. I was trying to write a templated method to take advantage of type inference rather than having to explicitly specify the types when I was using the interface.

**Question:**

Quite simply, why does Java have issues with including the package inside a Generic? My research did not find any obvious indications as to why Method Generics are not allowed to contain package paths. I am hoping that asking this question here will provide insight on why this might be occurring.

**Note:**

As a quick note, I already plan to redesign the code such that the I have a templated Interface instead of a templated Method. It seems that templated Interfaces do not have an issue when including the Package within the Generic definition. I am simply hoping that to understand why Java is having an issue with the way my code had previously been written.

Here is an example of my code:

Class TypeA

```
package otherPackage;
public class TypeA { /* Do Nothing */ }
```

Class TypeB

```
package otherPackage;
public class TypeB { /* Do Nothing */ }
```

Interface SomeInterface

```
package genericsTest;   
public interface SomeInterface {
    <U, T> void someMethod (U u, T t);
}
```

Class SomeClassOne

```
// This works
package genericsTest;
import otherPackage.TypeA;
import otherPackage.TypeB;
public class SomeClassOne implements SomeInterface 
{
    @Override
    public <TypeA, TypeB> void someMethod (TypeA a, TypeB b) 
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }
}
```

Class SomeClassTwo

```
// This doesn't seem to work
package genericsTest;
public class SomeClassTwo implements SomeInterface 
{
    @Override
    public <otherPackage.TypeA, otherPackage.TypeB> 
        void someMethod (otherPackage.TypeA a, otherPackage.TypeB b) 
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }
}
```

If it helps / matters, I am using Intellij with OpenJDK 1.8.0_131.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public <TypeA, TypeB> void someMethod (TypeA a, TypeB b)` is specifying the "name"/"placeholder" of the generic type (not it's actual constraint), so `otherPackage.TypeA` is an invalid "name" of a generic type.  Instead, it needs to be something more like...

```
public <TA extends otherPackage.TypeA, TB extends otherPackage.TypeB> void someMethod (TA a, TB b) {...}
```

depending on what you're attempting to achieve.

Although...

```
public void someMethod (otherPackage.TypeA a, otherPackage.TypeB b) {...}
```

would equate to the same thing, so that raises more questions

> Both of the options that you have suggesting provide the following error for me: "Method does not override method from its superclass". I forgot to include the @Overrides in my original submission. They have been added in for clarity.

Sorry, missed the `interface`

You need to define the constraints within `interface`, either something like...

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public <U extends otherPackage.TypeA, T extends otherPackage.TypeB> void someMethod(U u, T t);
}
```

which would then allow you to do...

```
public class SomeClassOne implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    public <U extends otherPackage.TypeA, T extends otherPackage.TypeB> void someMethod(U u, T t) {
    }

}
```

or, as I suspect you want to...

```
public interface SomeInterface<U, T> {
    public void someMethod(U u, T t);
}
```

which would allow you to do...

```
public class SomeClassOne implements SomeInterface<otherPackage.TypeA, otherPackage.TypeB> {

    @Override
    public void someMethod(TypeA u, TypeB t) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Both of the options that you have suggesting provide the following error for me: "Method does not override method from its superclass".

I forgot to include the @Overrides in my original submission. They have been added in for clarity.

Based on what you are describing, I think its mildly odd that there is no error when I include the package/constraint with a Class/Interface generic. 

For example: ```public class SomeClassOne implements SomeInterface<otherPackage.TypeA, otherPackage.TypeB>``` and Interface: ```public Interface SomeInterface <U, T>```

Comment: @Thaedrid `SomeInterface` needs to define the constraints that could be used

Comment: I am familiar with generic bounding. Unfortunately, my types do not share a common parent beyond Object. The only real constraint that I have is the package that the items are contained in. If it helps understand the problem, TypeA and TypeB are both Autogenerated classes so I do not have the ability to modify them in order to add common parents within each package.

Comment: Thanks! You've definitely answered my original question regarding the "name" / "placeholder". Is there a reason why you are allowed to include the constraint/package on the class/interface definition line but not on the method definition line? Is that just a quirk of the language?

Comment: No, I've demonstrated that, if you included the constraint, you can include the `package.class` in the constraint, the problem is, you're mixing the "place holder name" with the "constraint" type.  So `<otherPackage.TypeA>` is invalid, but `<T extends otherPackage.TypeA>` is valid. I'll update the answer a little, as I was using auto complete to speed things up ;)